# Can a Python script in a (sub)module import from upstream in its directory hierarchy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, sys.path

I realize there are a slew of posts on SO related to Python and imports, but it seems like a fair number of these posts are asking about import rules/procedures with respect to creating an actual Python package (vs just a project with multiple directories and python files). I am very new to Python and just need some more basic clarification on what is and is not possible with regard to access/importing within the context of multiple py files in a project directory.

Let's say you have the following project directory (to be clear, this is not a package that is somewhere on sys.path, but say, on your Desktop):

```
myProject/
├── __init__.py
├── scriptA.py
└── subfolder
    ├── __init__.py
    └── scriptB.py
    └── subsubfolder
        ├── __init__.py
        └── scriptC.py
        └── foo.py
```

Am I correct in understanding that the only way `scriptC.py` could import and use methods or classes within `scriptB.py` if `scriptC.py` is run directly via `$ python scriptC.py` and from within the `subsubfolder` directory is if I add the parent directory and path to `scriptB.py` to the Python path at runtime via `sys.path` ?

It is possible, however, for `scriptC.py` to import `foo.py` or for `scriptB.py` to import `scriptC.py` or `foo.py` without dealing with `sys.path`, correct? Adjacent py files and py files in subdirectories are accessible just by using relative import paths, you just can't import python scripts that live in parent or sibling directories (without using sys.path) ?

Comment: The simple solution is to put the directory containing `myprojects/` into your PYTHONPATH environment variable. Don't forget to `export PYTHONPATH`

Comment: @PM2Ring And unless you do that, there's no way to have scriptC.py import scriptB.py if you want to run scriptC.py from within its own directory, correct?

Comment: "No way" is absolutely incorrect. There are *lots* of ways, depending on how ugly of hacks you want to get into.

Comment: That said, putting a runnable script in `subfolder/subsubfolder/scriptC.py` is following bad practices. Even if you have a module that defines an entrypoint there, your `setup.py` should tell setuptools to create a top-level script invoking it. Then you'll have a `scriptC` **command**.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the comments, those hacks involve sys.path, right? Basically telling Python to include those scripts your trying to import at runtime?

Comment: No, the hacks don't all involve `sys.path`. The import mechanism is fully programmable. If you want to write the code for it, you can make it do whatever you damned well want to. You could tell it to get code from a zip file (well, that's built-in these days), from a web site; you could write something to make it import code from github... so *of course* you can make it get code from a parent directory. But it's an ugly hack, and you wouldn't need it if you were following best practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What's Possible

Anything.

No, really. See [the `imp` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html), the [the `imputil` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imputil.html) -- take a look at how [the `zipimport` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipimport.html) is written if you want some inspiration.

If you can get a string with your module's code in a variable, you can get a module into `sys.modules` using the above, and perhaps hack around with its contents using [the `ast` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) on the way.

A custom import hook that looks in parent directories? Well within the range of possibilities.

---

#### What's Best Practice

What you're proposing isn't actually good practice. The best-practice approach looks more like the following:

```
myProject/
├── setup.py
└── src/
    ├── moduleA.py
    └── submodule/
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── moduleB.py
        └── subsubmodule/
            ├── __init__.py
            └── moduleC.py
```

Here, the top of your project is always in `myProject/src`. If you use `setup.py` to configure `moduleA:main`, `submodule.moduleB:main` and `submodule.subsubmodule.moduleC:main` as entry points (perhaps named `scriptA`, `scriptB` and `scriptC`), then the functions named `main` in each of those modules would be invoked when the user ran the (automatically generated by setuptools) scripts so named.

With this layout (and appropriate setuptools use), your `moduleC.py` can absolutely `import moduleA`, or `import submodule.moduleB`.

---

Another approach, which doesn't involve entrypoints, to invoke the code in your `moduleC.py` (while keeping the module's intended hierarchy intact, and assuming you're in a virtualenv where `python setup.py develop` has been run) like so:

```
python -m submodule.subsubmodule.moduleC
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough answer here, much appreciated. Just to be clear, simply using virtualenv and activating it within this directory doesn't get around this, correct? In other words, creating a virtual environment wouldn't allow me to execute `scriptC.py` within its own directory and be able to import `scriptB.py`, ect, correct?

Comment: If you install it into the virtualenv, as with `python setup.py develop` (to install a link to your source tree) or `python setup.py install` (to install a static copy of your code),  (1) sure, that works; (2) it works because it puts the location of the code into `sys.path` (albeit in a manner not considered to be a hack).

Comment: The other thing is that if you run code as a script in that way, it's losing its position in the module hierarchy. That means you can end up with your `__main__` module being `scriptC`, but **also** having a separate `submodule.subsubmodule.scriptC` in memory. That has some potentially nasty side effects, and it's best avoided.

Comment: Ok, so assuming this hypothetical project directory has a `setup.py` file, you're saying that if you install and activate virtualenv AND then install this project directory as a package in that virtualenv installation by running `setup.py`, you could run `scriptC.py` locally within its own directory and it would import `scriptB.py`, etc (although that's not best practices) ?

Comment: not just "not best practices", but "would actively create some very hard-to-track bugs", but yes.

Comment: That said, I'd strongly advise thinking about "modules" and "scripts" as two separate things; it'll help you reason better about what's going on and why the best practices are what they are.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Can you explain the use of `:main` when configuring in `setup.py`? I don't understand. Is `main` a function that has been defined in each of `moduleA`, `moduleB` and `moduleC`? What would be wrong with setting up with `packages=["moduleA", "submodule.moduleB", "submodule.subsubmodule.moduleC"]` without the `main` bits?

Comment: The point is that `moduleA:main` is an entry point -- it's a specific function that can be called to invoke your code. If just importing the module runs the code you're trying to encapsulate, there are a bunch of things you can't do -- you can't import it just once and run it multiple times; you can't use static analysis tools that import the module and inspect its AST; etc. To be clear, `packages=["moduleA", "submodule.moduleB"]` is perfectly fine -- nothing in this answer should be read to the contrary -- but you don't want to try to use modules as if they were entry points.